# Getting null value when passing ID from req.banker to MongoDB query but works with hardcoded ID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm encountering an issue where I'm getting a **null** value when passing the **bankerId** from the **req.banker** object to a MongoDB query. However, when I hardcode the ID, the query works as expected. I've checked the data type of the **bankerId** and confirmed it's a string, but I'm still getting **null**. I've also verified that the **Banker** object with the provided **bankerId** exists in the MongoDB database.

Here is how I connected DB from my connection.js file:

```
require('dotenv').config();
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

async function connectToDatabase() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL);
    console.log("Db Connected Successfully");
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}

connectToDatabase();
```

Here is my code:

```
// Authenticate token middleware
async function authenticateToken(req, res, next) {
  const token = req.cookies.jwt;
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).send("No token found");
  }

  try {
    const banker = await jwt.verify(token, process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET);
    req.banker = banker;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return res.status(403).send("Invalid token");
  }

  next();
}

// Banker check middleware
async function bankerCheck(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.banker || !req.banker.id) {
    return res.send("Invalid banker ID");
  }

  const bankerId = req.banker.id.toString();

  try {
    Banker.findById(bankerId)
      .then((bankerData) => {
        console.log("bankerData: ", bankerData);

        if (!bankerData) {
          return res.send("Invalid banker id");
        }

        req.banker = bankerData;
        next();
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error in Banker.findById: ", err);
        res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
      });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
    res.status(500).send("Internal Server Error");
  }
}

// Dashboard route
router.get("/dashboard", authenticateToken, bankerCheck, (req, res) => {
  res.render("DashBoard/BankerHomeDashBoard");
});
```

I've tried adding logging to the **Banker.findById** query to further investigate the issue, but I can't seem to pinpoint the exact cause.

Steps to reproduce:

Start your Node.js application.
Make a request to the /banker/dashboard route.

Expected behavior:

The **bankerData** object should be populated with the banker's data.

Actual behavior:

The bankerData object is null.

Comment: Your `authenticateToken()` function is `async`, but you don't `await` the call.

Comment: can you point it out for understanding purpose.

Comment: `banker` is the result of an asynchronous call to `jwt.verify`, so it will not be available until that completes.

Comment: @Pointy authenticateToken is a middleware so the main function will only be called once next() is encountered so its alright, no need to wait there

Comment: @Kamran well it looks like that isn't working out. The `authenticateToken()` function will yield a Promise instance before `next()` is called, because it is an `async` function with an `await` in the middle.

Comment: 1. In your `authenticateToken` function do `console.log('token=',req.cookies.jwt)` to make sure you have the cookie. Then do `console.log('req.banker=',req.banker)` before you call `next()` to ensure `banker.id` is available. 2. In `bankerCheck` function `Banker.findById` will cast the `req.banker.id` to an ObjectId for you. However, you are mixing `try/catch` with `.then().catch()` which doesn't make any sense.